# If event $A$ happens with probability $p$, then when is event $B$ guaranteed to not be mutually exclusive with $A$?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

Say event $A$ happens with probability $p$. We want to find the probability $q$ of $B$ happening such that it ensures that $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive. Is this simply $q > 1-p$?

We have the relation
$$
P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)
$$
If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive then $P(A \cap B) = 0$

If $q > 1-p$, then P(A)+P(B) > 1, so this implies they're not mutually exclusive otherwise P(A \cup B) > 1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly the condition that does it.  And you can't do better than that because if $B = A^c$, they are mutually exclusive with $p+q=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Can we do some analogous analysis to guarantee 2 variables are not independent?

Comment: No.  For any $p$ and $q$ in $[0,1]$ it is possible to have independent events with probabilities $p$ and $q$.  All you need is $P(A \cap B) = p q$, $P(A \cap B^c) = p (1-q)$, $P(A^c \cap B) = (1-p) q$ and $P(A^c \cap B^c) = (1-p)(1-q)$.